# Filter in pandas using operators

Tags: python, pandas, operator-keyword

I have Three variables as

```
a='col1'
b='=='
c=2
```

I have Pandas dataframe as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 2], 'col2': [10, 11, 12]},dtype=object)
```

And I wanted to filter for `col1=2`, So I wrote

```
df.query("@a @b @c")
```

Which is throwing below error

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    __pd_eval_local_a __pd_eval_local_b __pd_eval_local_c
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can some one help me how to achieve this using these three variables?

Thanks,

Comment: you could just do `df.query(a + b + c)`

Comment: yup, Got it. But When I converted c to string variable it is working! Should this conversion be a problem while filtering? please help!

Comment: I don't use `query` so I don't know the evaluation rules but if you just want to construct a query string, it's less hassle to just concatenate all strings to make a single string here, also even if what you wanted to use did work, I think it would fail because `@c` will make the query `'col1' == '2'` which would filter for the string `'2'` rather than the numerical `2`

Comment: Seems a bit of a weird use of `df.query` here... as @Ed says... a `''.join((a,b,c))` will work - but I'm pondering your use case here...

Comment: @EdChum Can you please suggest me how do you achieve in this case?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, please edit your question with a complete example, also what are you really trying to achieve here that our suggestions don't achieve

Comment: Then convert to `str` - `df.query(a+b+str(c))`

Comment: @EdChum So, I wanted to filter records which have numeric 2 in `col1` column from pandas dataframe. Here I get values to be filtered into variables. So, using these variables, how to filter records. You, please suggest any workable method in pandas. Thanks!

Comment: I already suggested a method that would work, so what else are you after?

Comment: @jezrael, `a+b+str(c)` will not work for strings. Example: `c=='aaa'; a+b+str(c) == 'col1==aaa'`. And `aaa` is not quoted so it will be treated as a column name...

Answer (score 1):

```
In [214]: df
Out[214]:
  col1 col2 col3
0    0   10  aaa
1    1   11  bbb
2    2   12  ccc

In [215]: a='col1'; b='=='; c=2   # <--- `c` is `int`

In [216]: df.query(a + b + '@c')
Out[216]:
  col1 col2 col3
2    2   12  ccc

In [217]: a='col3'; b='=='; c='aaa'   # <--- `c` is `str`

In [218]: df.query(a + b + '@c')
Out[218]:
  col1 col2 col3
0    0   10  aaa
```

it will also work with datetime dtypes, as `.query()` would take care of dtypes:

```
In [226]: df['col4'] = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', freq='99D', periods=len(df))

In [227]: df
Out[227]:
  col1 col2 col3       col4
0    0   10  aaa 2017-01-01
1    1   11  bbb 2017-04-10
2    2   12  ccc 2017-07-18

In [228]: a='col4'; b='=='; c='2017-01-01'

In [229]: df.query(a + b + '@c')
Out[229]:
  col1 col2 col3       col4
0    0   10  aaa 2017-01-01
```

Comment: '@c'  what is this?  Python operator?

Comment: @ScottBoston, this how we can access variables in `.query()` and `.eval()` methods, otherwise not quoted strings are treated as column names

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the use of query if that's not a requierement, using eval :

```
a='col1'
b='=='
c='2'

instruction ="df[\"" + a + "\"]" + b  + c
>>>> 'df["col1"]==2'
df[eval(instruction)]
>>>> 
    col1    col2
  2  2      12
```